EF Core 8: migrations adds AlterColumn to every column, for subsequent migrations
I have an old application in .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1. I have successfully migrated to .NET 8 and EF Core 8. The migrations folder was HUGE, so I reset the migrations, deleting all records in the [__EFMigrationsHistory] table and deleted the migration folder (the migrations folder is in a separate project.
I successfully ran the initial migration and EF Core created the class with all existing tables, columns, indexes, etc. As the database already exists, I manually added the migrations record to the [__EFMigrationsHistory] table.
I then had to add a new table. When I ran the Add-Migration, the resulting class is HUGE (should have only contained the necessary code for the new table). It includes code for (I think) every column in the database, such as the following:
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
            name: "TenantId",
            schema: "Common",
            table: "XrmOrganization",
            type: "uniqueidentifier",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(Guid),
            oldType: "uniqueidentifier",
            oldNullable: true)
            .Annotation("Relational:ColumnOrder", 300);

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "StatusCode",
            schema: "Common",
            table: "XrmOrganization",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int",
            oldNullable: true)
            .Annotation("Relational:ColumnOrder", 211);

Any migration I try to add, adds hundreds (maybe thousands) of these lines of code, altering the columns. As a remedy, I have manually deleted all these lines of code, but I would like to know the root cause and how to solve this issue, as the migrations file has more than 110 thousand lines.
Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.


Remove all migrations and Snapshot. 2) Generate migration Initial, clear Up/Down methods. Next migrations should work as expected.


Thnk you for your response @SvyatoslavDanyliv. That's similar to what I did (instead of clearing up/down methods, I added a return; at the beggining of the up method. However when I try to create the migration for the new table (subsequent migration), it adds those thousands of lines for every column. Any other ideas?

Annotation is suspicious part. Do you set ColumnOrder somehow?

Yes I do, most of the properties have an Annotation to set the column order in the created tables (ex: [Column(Order = 402)]). Will try to delete some of these Annotations.

Strangely removing the [Column(Order = XXXX)] solved the problem. Thank you for your guidance @SvyatoslavDanyliv.

For anyone with this problem in the future, I solved the problem removing the [Column(Order=XXX)] annotation, as suggested by @SvyatoslavDanyliv.
